# Twitter REST API: Bad Authentication data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

I'm trying to post a tweet but for any reason it doesn't work as expected.

I suspect that the issue could be related to the `signature` string, but following what twitter says according to [signing](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures) requests looks ok.

Here is my code:

```
function postTweet(user_id, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret) {
  var base_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json',
    oauth_nonce = randomString(),
    oauth_signature,
    oauth_timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
    reqArray,
    req,
    signature_base_string,
    signing_key;

  reqArray = [
    "include_entities=true",
    'oauth_consumer_key="' + CONFIG.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY + '"',
    'oauth_nonce="' + oauth_nonce + '"',
    'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"',
    'oauth_timestamp="' + oauth_timestamp + '"',
    'oauth_token="' + AccessToken + '"',
    'oauth_version="1.0"',
    'status=' + encodeURIComponent("hello world")
  ];

  req = reqArray.sort().join('&');

  signature_base_string = "POST&" + encodeURIComponent(base_url) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(req);

  signing_key = CONFIG.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET + '&' + AccessTokenSecret;

  oauth_signature = encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signature_base_string, signing_key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));

  return $http.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', {
    status: 'hello world'
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response;
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

[image]

As a response, I get that:

[image]

**UPDATE**

considering that in my project I already have `$cordovaOauthUtility` I started using it this way:

```
function postTweet(accessToken, accessTokenSecret) {
  var params, signature;

  params = {
    include_entities: true,
    oauth_consumer_key: CONFIG.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
    oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_token: accessToken,
    oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
    oauth_version: "1.0"
  };

  signature = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature('POST', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', params, { status: "hello" }, CONFIG.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET, accessTokenSecret);

  return $http.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', {
    status: "hello"
  }, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: signature.authorization_header
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

After trying all the posibilities, the problem persist. Here I paste a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/avanYY0EoOGwMARzgZtw) where I have my code.

Comment: Can you add the request as show by the dev tool as well?

Comment: I attached a capture of my request @JonSampson

Comment: I dont see "include_entities" as one of the accepted params in the api docs https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Comment: @JeremyHamm according to https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures, `include_entities=true` is a required param to generate the signature

Answer (score 2):

You are using crypto's `HmacSHA256` but sending `HMAC-SHA1` as the `oauth_signature_method` parameter which is the twitter one.

You should probably change your code to

```
oauth_signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signature_base_string, signing_key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

If you look at your `authorization` header, you can also notice that something is wrong with it. Indeed, you can see that the `oauth_nonce` and the `oauth_version` are prefixed by a `&` sign, which shouldn't be the case and most likely mean to the api you are not specifying them. It probably comes from the fact you are using the same `reqArray` to construct both the signature and the header, or your code is not updated.

You also probably don't want to change the global headers sent from your app, in case another request is sent to another api at the same time. Rather, you should send this `authorization` header only  for this specific xhr.

```
return $http.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', {
  status: 'hello world',
}, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: auth,
  },
})
```

Comment: You were right, but unfortunately, the problem persists. I've updated the code including the fix.

Comment: @DevStarlight my bad for the edit, forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're clearly adding `oauth_token` in your request array but it didn't show up in the screenshot? Is the AccessToken in the params undefined?

**EDIT**

According to the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests), we must append double quotes to the headers. Try this?

```
reqArray = [
    "include_entities=true",
    'oauth_consumer_key="'+CONFIG.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY+'"',
    'oauth_nonce="'+oauth_nonce+'"',
    'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"',
    'oauth_timestamp="'+oauth_timestamp+'"',
    'oauth_token="'+AccessToken+'"',
    'oauth_version="1.0"',
    'status='+encodeURIComponent("hello world")
  ];
```

Comment: I've updated the picture where the token was missing.

Comment: still doesn't work, but now It drops an "Authorization required" instead of "Bad authenticated data". I've updated my main image & my code.

Comment: Dang. I checked the docs again. after uriEncoding, >>> 6. If there are key/value pairs remaining, append a comma ‘,’ and a space ‘ ‘. Can you try it with spaces and see if it works?

Comment: like that? `'status='+encodeURIComponent("hello world") + ' '`

Comment: Right now, I think it's this before joining and encoding:
OAuth oauth_token="GmHxMAgYy",oauth_version="1.0" 
Can you change it to this?
'OAuth oauth_token="GmHxMAgYy', oauth_version="1.0"

Comment: That's what `$cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature` returns but I can do it manually like before the update

Comment: after trying your solution, it keeps throwing an error. I've updated my initial post to clarify the problem even more than it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes.

I've downloaded your plnkr bundle and added a read only application key set. I only had to set up and make one change to get a `{"request":"\/1.1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST."}` response. Initially I was receiving `{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`.

**Remove `status: "hello"` from between the curly brackets `{ }` where you create your signature.**

```
signature = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature('POST', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', params, { }, twitter.consumer_secret, twitter.access_token_secret);
```

My request headers become the following:

```
:authority:api.twitter.com
:method:POST
:path:/1.1/statuses/update.json
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
authorization:OAuth     oauth_consumer_key="x",oauth_nonce="QFMmqiasFs",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_token="y",oauth_timestamp="1496340853",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="7Ts91LKcP%2FrYsLcF5WtryCvZQFU%3D"
content-length:18
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin:http://localhost
referer:http://localhost/twits/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36
```

Googling eventually led me to a tutorial: 
[Displaying the Twitter Feed within Your Ionic App](http://blog.ionic.io/displaying-the-twitter-feed-within-your-ionic-app/). I noted his general `createTwitterSignature` function does not take parameters and tweaked your code similarly.

```
function createTwitterSignature(method, url) {
    var token = angular.fromJson(getStoredToken());
    var oauthObject = {
        oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
        oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
        oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
        oauth_token: token.oauth_token,
        oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
        oauth_version: "1.0"
    };
    var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature(method, url, oauthObject, {}, clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
}
```

I've read conflicting things about why there should/shouldn't be other parameters there, but I believe the signature is just supposed to be the basis of access and doesn't hash in every operation you want to perform - see [Understanding Request Signing For Oauth 1.0a Providers](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/understanding-request-signing-oauth-1-0a-providers/).

Comment: finally It was a conflict between the parameter placed in the signature! got it to work. Thanks!